# Binding a dictionary to a WinForms grid (or combo)?

Tags: .net, vb.net, data-binding

You have a pseudo-table class and a pseudo-row class.  The row is somewhat generic and has no strongly-typed fields.  It follows the typical dictionary interface

```
Dim age As Object = person("Age") 'accessed via default property Item
```

vs

```
Dim age As Integer = person.Age 'an actual property typed as an Integer
```

**What's the pattern to use so that we can bind our pseudo table and its rows to a grid or combo box?**

```
Dim rs As New clsResultSet(tblPeople)
Dim id As Object   = rs(0)("Id")   '913
Dim name As Object = rs(0)("Name") 'Ted
Dim age As Object  = rs(0)("Age")  '43
Dim occupation As Object = rs(0)("Occupation") 'cab driver

grd.DataSource = rs 'In grid I expect to see Name, Age, Occupation columns

cbo.DataSource    = rs
cbo.DisplayMember = "Name" 'could we do this?
cbo.ValueMember   = "Id"   '...and this?
```

I read all about IList, IBindingList, BindingSource, etc., tried some things, and I'm still puzzling over how to get this right.  Most examples I've found expect your record objects to be strongly typed (e.g. person.Age rather than person("Age")).

Here are some simple classes to start with:

```
Public Class clsResultSet 'Like a DataTable
    Inherits List(Of clsRecord)

    Private mdicFields As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)

    Public Sub New(vdt As DataTable) 'Loaded from table
        For Each bdc As DataColumn In vdt.Columns
            Me.mdicFields.Add(bdc.ColumnName, bdc)
        Next
        For Each vdr As DataRow In vdt.Rows
            Me.Add(New clsRecord(vdr, Me))
        Next
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Fields As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
        Get
            Return Me.mdicFields
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Public Class clsRecord 'Like a DataRow
    Inherits Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    Private mrs As clsResultSet

    Protected Friend Sub New(vdr As DataRow, vrs As clsResultSet)
        Me.mrs = vrs
        For Each bPair As KeyValuePair(Of String, Object) In vrs.Fields
            Me.Add(bPair.Key, vdr(bPair.Key))
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

This question, as asked, was answered.  I [reframed it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192379/create-custom-datatable-which-is-bindable-to-winforms-controls) since I didn't get to the root of my problem.

Comment: Which VB version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to directly bind to dictionary objects. Here's a quick workaround for a combobox with a fixed DataSource. Create a new list with the desired properties using Select and anonymous objects (works with Visual Studio 2008 and newer):

```
Dim rs As New clsResultSet(tblPeople)
cbo.DataSource = rs.Select(Function(x) New With {.Name = x("Name"), .Id = x("Id")}).ToList()
cbo.DisplayMember = "Name"
cbo.ValueMember   = "Id"
```

I suppose you could use a similar approach to bind to a DataGridView, but I would recommend using a strongly-typed class instead (a Person class with properties Name, Age, etc.), unless it's a read-
only DataGridView that won't change.

**Edit:**

You might be interested in the Remarks section of the [DataGridView.DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx) documentation. Basically the DataSource can be either an `IList`, `IListSource`, `IBindingList` or `IBindingListView`. DataTable and DataSet classes implement `IListSource` so it might be worth trying to implement this interface for your own class.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback.  What's interesting is that the native DataRow has anonymous columns (e.g. dictionary-like access to column values).  Basically I'm trying to create a custom DataRow/DataTable/DataSet to help enforce shop standards.

Comment: Oops.  I had already reframed the question (since you did indeed answer it as I asked it); see the crosslink now in the post.  I did this before I noticed your Edit.  I will definitely read what you've provided as I have time.  Thanks a bunch for trying to help.