# Create custom DataTable which is bindable to WinForms controls?

Tags: .net, vb.net, data-binding, ado.net

Our shop primarily use "ADO objects" (I'm referring to `DataSet`, `DataTable`, and `DataRow`) for marshaling around data and manipulating it on forms and in grids.  We are experimenting with creating shop-flavored counterparts to the native ADO objects so that we can impose our in-house standards on top of them.

Implementing this is straightforward with one exception: I want our objects to be bindable to controls.

I'm aware of IList, IBindingList, BindingSource, etc. and have looked at and experimented with these, but I am falling short when it comes to making a class *with no hard property names* bindable.  The native ADO objects are not strongly typed by default.  You have column values that you access via the `Item` property (e.g. `row("Age")` or `row.Item("Age")`).  The binding examples I've found online deal with strong-typed objects (e.g. `row.Age`).  Essentially, we want to create custom ADO objects (not inherited from the native ones) that still retain their ability to bind to controls.

*Is there a bare-bones example of how this could be implemented?*

In a grid I would expect to see columns `Name`, `Age` and `Occupation` from a row where these properties are exposed via `row("Name")`, `row("Age")` and `row("Occupation")`.  This must be doable as this is exactly what the native `DataTable` and `DataRow` provide.

*This is a refinement of an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181324/binding-a-dictionary-to-a-winforms-grid-or-combo).*

Comment: What is your question? DataTables are bindable

Comment: I think you're barking up the wrong tree with trying to implement "Item(...)" for binding. I tried making my own DataRow type object, implementing "Item(...)" and all its overloads, but these never get called when binding. You need to look at another way of making the control believe there is a property called "Age", just not sure what that would be yet...

Comment: msarchet -- Without inheriting from existing ADO.NET classes, how do you implement a bare-bones DataTable/DataRow yourself (all your code and none of Microsoft's)?  Your custom classes should be bindable to grids and controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to use the ITypedList interface, which works in conjunction with PropertyDescriptor. The clearest article I have found on this is here:

http://blog.lab49.com/archives/705

I had attempted this myself a while back, and will be giving it another try based on this article.

Comment: Ahh... at first glance this looks like it might suit my needs.  I will get back more definitely as I have time to read it more fully and try it out.  Thanks for the help, Andy.